# Need help with Regular Expression in Zend Famework

Tags: regex, zend-framework

Currently Im developing on a website with Zend framework.

I needed to develop a location field similar to http://www.truelocal.com.au/

Which allow user to input PostCode Values (consist of 4 numbers) or Suburb Name (in the format of Suburb Name comma symbol space State abbreviations (State abbreviations consist exact three letters) )

Example input for Postcode: 2000
Example input for Suburb Name: MANLY, NSW or SYDNEY, NSW or PALM BEACH, QLD

I need the validate the location value to ensure these 2 format

I found out that in Zend framework you can use use Regular Expression in Zend_Validate_Regex for it.

```
$myValidator = new Zend_Validate_Regex('Regular Expression');
$myValidator->setMessage('Your validation message goes here',Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH);
```

But how can I write a Regular Expression which check in these 2 Regular Expression format (PostCode Values (consist of 4 numbers) or Suburb Name (in the format of Suburb Name comma symbol space State abbreviations (State abbreviations consist exact three letters) ) in just one input field.

In this particular scenario is it feasible to do in Zend_Validate_Regex

If possible can you teach me how to write the Regular expression for it.

Thanks you so much in advance! Very Appreicated!

Thanks for reading and have a good weekend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this regular expression:

```
^(\d{4}|[A-Z ]+, [A-Z]{3})$
```